# Simple Form in an email...is it possible?

Tags: email, forms

I'm designing an html email for a Holiday Art Market. The request is simply for graphic design, make it pretty-put the date/time etc., but I'm wondering if I can also implement an RSVP form in the email: Are you coming, yes or no? Can this be done in an email, or do I need to redirect to a website? If it can be done, how?

Thanks again SOF community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simplest solution - if all you need is a yes or no answer - is to embed two links, one for yes and one for no, with identifying information already in the querystring parameters of the links, e.g.

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/rsvp.aspx?by=email@receiver.com&response=no

http://www.yourdomain.com/rsvp.aspx?by=email@receiver.com&response=yes
```

Comment: I don't know database language, but DO know the basics of html and CSS. What additional items do I need to take care of on my server to get the aspx to work? Thank you for the above answer by the way.

Comment: Read the query parameters on postback from Request.Params to extract the values.  string by = Request.Params["by"]; string response = Request.Params["response"];  A comment is too small to show you you to insert them into your database.

Comment: @rashneon: you will need some kind of programming on the back end to process the rsvp responses, .aspx is the extension for asp.net but is just an example. Ask whoever did your photography web site (it's in php and the home page photo is awesome!) to knock something out for you (or email/call me)

Comment: I did the majority of my site myself with a lot of mentorship from the guy that did the small php portion, so I'll take your advice and see if he's got a free moment to hook up the back end. If not, I'll definitely contact you. Oh, thanks so much for the compliment. I dig your logo/avatar btw!

Comment: @rashneon: good luck! it should not be difficult, there is really only one function rsvp yes/no ;-) And thanks for the compliment, the logo is by Stan Carter, http://www.estanislaoinc.com/portfolio.html

Comment: @rashneon: one more thing to consider is embedding an 'authorization' token in the email'd links to limit them to a one-time use; this could be a simple hash of the recipient's name. The purpose of this is to prevent bots/crawlers/scammers/spammers from screwing up your RSVP counts/records

Answer (score 1):

Last time I tried it (back in about 2001) it worked fine.  Just make sure the action= attribute of the form tag contains an absolute URL.

Jim.

Answer (score 0):

I would not add it in an email. People would be cautions about it with good reason - there is no easy way to tell where the "action" is pointing to; and a customer would not take kindly to being redirected to a site without their knowledge after they click the submit button.

I would *highly* recommend linking to a site. Or - even better - generate two links, using their email address and the answer in the querystring. i.e.

```
<a href = "www.yoursite.com/submit?from={$SenderEmailAddress}&answer=yes">Yes</a>

<a href = "www.yoursite.com/submit?from={$SenderEmailAddress}&answer=no">No</a>
```

That way you can make sure that people arnt accidentally answering twice or answering when they didnt receive the invite.